# How to configure MDB in JBoss 7.4 with multiple resource adapters?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss EAP 7.4.0.GA.

I have the following resource-adapters configuration in `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
  <resource-adapters>
    <resource-adapter id="ActiveMQ-A">
        <archive>
            activemq.rar
        </archive>
        <!--Configuration tags omitted-->
    </resource-adapter>
    <resource-adapter id="ActiveMQ-B">
        <archive>
            activemq.rar
        </archive>
        <!--Configuration tags omitted-->
    </resource-adapter>
    <resource-adapter id="ActiveMQ-C">
        <archive>
            activemq.rar
        </archive>
        <!--Configuration tags omitted-->
    </resource-adapter>
    <resource-adapter id="ActiveMQ-J">
        <archive>
            activemq.rar
        </archive>
        <!--Configuration tags omitted-->
    </resource-adapter>
  </resource-adapters>
</subsystem>
```

and the following MDB config

```xml
<mdb>
  <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq.rar"/>
  <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
</mdb>
```

I've tried many things for `resource-adapter-name`:

- `"${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq.rar}"`
- `"activemq.rar"`
- `"${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"`

but I still get the following error when deployed:

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.ra.activemq"],
```

What `resource-adapter-name` should I use to fix this error given that I've multiple resource adapters?